# How do I open Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Earlier I have been able to open Jupyter Notebook but now I get this messenge:

`The file /Users/theaborup/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command does not exist.`

I'm still able to open JupyterLab.

I have tried finding the file on my computer but I'm not the best at macos.